# How can I carry more ammo in BioShock?

Tags: bioshock

Is there a tonic or something else that increases the amount of ammunition you can carry? **Upgrading weapon clip size doesn't increase total ammo capacity**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***There is no way to increase your total ammo capacity in BioShock,*** but it is possible in BioShock 2.

From [this thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/945381-bioshock-2/53734352),

> The Alpha Series' second Research Bonus is an increased ammo capacity - I think the amount is 20% of the base capacity.